# How can I perform search on Redis Hash?

Tags: hash, redis, node-redis

I have many hash in my game which have values like

```
HMSET('hash1', 'level', 25, 'connected', 2)
HMSET('hash2', 'level', 50, 'connected', 2)
HMSET('hash3', 'level', 15, 'connected', 3)
HMSET('hash3', 'level', 15, 'connected', 2)
```

I want to find the hash which has level value 50.
Can I Find the hash by this or not, if yes then how?

Also specifying 2 queries like level is 15 and connected must be less than 3?

Answer (score 2):

Redis doesn't support secondary index out of the box.  But, you can model it using different built in data structures like Sorted Set, you can read more about it here: https://redis.io/topics/indexes

If you want a more advanced solution you should check [RediSearch](https://RediSearch.io),  RediSearch is a Redis module adding Secondary Index and Full-Text and engine.